# Should the authentication/authorization middleware return 403 for missing api routes?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and getting into the setup of the `Startup.cs` file. I am aware that from the reading that the order of the middleware has importance.

From this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-2.0

There is the following diagram: [image]

It indicates that if the authentication middleware provided is setup correctly, and then if the authentication fails, then regardless if the route exists or not a unauthorized response (HTTP 401 - Unauthorized) is sent.

In my scenario, I'm getting a response of HTTP 404 (Not Found) for routes that do not exist. Before I post up some code, is my understanding correct of how the middleware should behave?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you read *regardless if the route exists or not a unauthorized response (HTTP 401 - Unauthorized) is sent*?

Comment: @DavidG My mistake - I didn't mean to say I read it, but rather I interpreted it from the diagram. I am trying to clarify if authentication fails (e.g. header is missing), will it proceed to the next middleware in the chain or will it exit immediately.

Comment: OK, how did you interpret that from the diagram then?

Comment: The first set of arrows that specifies *unauthorized request*. I'm guessing you alluding to that this is not a correct interpretation.

Comment: Well sending back 401 has it's uses, for example to obfuscate the endpoint URLs from unscrupulous visitors, but that's pretty uncommon. Other than that, just send back a 404.

Comment: So, to sum up, that answer to my original question, the authentication middleware does not exit and return a 401 if it fails authentication, but rather it forwards down the chain at which point MVC kicks in and returns a 404 if the requested route is missing.

Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes. Authentication is not designed to refuse anonymous requests, that's the job of Authorization. Authorization takes place at a specific endpoint, but if the endpoint doesn't exist then it never happens.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments that emphasize the distinction between Authentication and Authorization, this quote is quite useful (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware):

> Authentication **doesn't short-circuit** unauthenticated requests.
>   Although Authentication Middleware authenticates requests,
>   authorization (and rejection) occurs **only after MVC selects** a specific
>   Razor Page or MVC controller and action.

If there is no Razor Page or MVC controller to select, this will result in an HTTP 404 (Not Found) before the authorization checks would produce an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized).

Keep in mind that authorization attributes can be specified at the action level, meaning that the authorization checks wouldn't have enough information to accept or reject a request until the page or controller/action is selected (e.g. a Controller can be decorated with the [Authorize] attribute while specific actions therein are decorated with the [AllowAnonymous] attribute).